# Too many Re-renders React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code pls ?**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

const Createcolumn = () => {
  const [sum, setSum] = useState('');
  const [dailySum, setDailySum] = useState(0);
  const [daysOfWork, setDaysOfWork] = useState(0);
  const [fare, setFare] = useState(0);
  const dailySumHandler = (e) => {
    setDailySum(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const daysOfWorkHandler = (e) => {
    setDaysOfWork(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const fareHandler = (e) => {
    setFare(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  setSum(dailySum * daysOfWork + fare);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="column">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <h1>Daily</h1>
        <h1>Days of Work</h1>
        <h1>Fare</h1>
        <h1>Total</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="column">
        <div>
          <h1>Nodirbek</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={dailySumHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={daysOfWorkHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={fareHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{sum}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Createcolumn;
```

****I cannot set my Sum to h1, it is saying too much render**
*I tried to make a function as well, but it doesn't work either***

****I cannot set my Sum to h1, it is saying too much render**
*I tried to make a function as well, but it doesn't work either***

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're calling this directly into your `render`

```
setSum(dailySum * daysOfWork + fare);
```

Once `setSum` gets triggered, it will cause UI re-rendering which calls `render` function again. And again `setSum` will continue being called (it's like deadlock)

Here is a possible fix

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Createcolumn = () => {
  const [dailySum, setDailySum] = useState(0);
  const [daysOfWork, setDaysOfWork] = useState(0);
  const [fare, setFare] = useState(0);
  const dailySumHandler = (e) => {
    setDailySum(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const daysOfWorkHandler = (e) => {
    setDaysOfWork(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const fareHandler = (e) => {
    setFare(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="column">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <h1>Daily</h1>
        <h1>Days of Work</h1>
        <h1>Fare</h1>
        <h1>Total</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="column">
        <div>
          <h1>Nodirbek</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={dailySumHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={daysOfWorkHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={fareHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{dailySum * daysOfWork + fare}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Createcolumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use calls to hook setters in the body of the function, it'll cause a rerender, which will cause a rerender, which will cause rerender, and so and so forth.

Instead initialize your value when you call the hook:
`const [sum, setSum] = useState(dailySum * daysOfWork + fare);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arrow function notation while calling those functions and pass the event that's what's causing re-renders.

Your code:

```
 </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={dailySumHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={daysOfWorkHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={fareHandler} />
        </div>
```

Fix:

```
 </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => dailySumHandler(e)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => daysOfWorkHandler(e)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => fareHandler(e)} />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The why:
You're changing the state in every render not based on some change in your component, remember how react works: you change the state => react re-render your component all over again.

At every render you tell react to change the state(`setSum(...)`) which will tell react to re-render, all over again, it enters a loop of render and a call to `setSum` which cause a re-render forever.

Solution:
Don't use state if your data can be computed based on other states, it looks like the `sum` only depends on other states, why create a state for it if you can calculate it easily from other states?

Delete the line:

```js
  const [sum, setSum] = useState('');
```

and just add the line(before the return statement)

```js
  let sum = (dailySum * daysOfWork + fare);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically the kind of scenario you want to use `useMemo` to solve:

```
import { useMemo } from "react"

const sum = useMemo(
    () => dailySum * daysOfWork + fare,
    [dailySum, daysOfWork, fare]
);
```

This allows you to automatically recompute the sum whenever any of its components changes without having to keep track of an additional state and setter.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that when you try to use setstate() before you bring in the
`return()` 
statement  it will bring out that error.
The solution is that the setSum() have to fire after the first render after the return statement